# scale intensitiey levels of ffmpeg filter output

Tags: video, ffmpeg

how does ffmpeg scale filter output intensities?
I have a blend/divide filter that divides 8 bit frames by an 8 bit image and saves the output into an xvid avi.

`blend=all_mode='divide':repeatlast=1`

I would like to understand how exactly ffmpeg maps the filter output (presumably a float?) to the 8 bit video output levels.

Does it depend on the intensity histogram of the frame? (i.e. if 99% of pixels are in the range 0 to 0.5 and 1% of pixels has a much larger intensity e.g. 1)

Is there a way to specifically provide a lookup table for this mapping at this step?

Answer (score 0):

the [source code](https://github.com/hhool/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/vf_blend.c) looks like this:

`DEFINE_BLEND8(divide, av_clip_uint8(B == 0 ? 255 : 255 * A / B))`

So I guess the answer is that the result gets multiplied by 255 and then clipped to 255